# why is need of mapping if same work done by using array in struct?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ether, mapping, struct

I muddle up with mapping use with struct.
this smart contract I used  array instead of mapping

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.*; 
contract MyContract{
    //here we can not assume the length off array so need counter on couter we can fatch data from index (counter)
  Person[] public people;
  uint256 public peopleCount;
    struct Person{
        string _firstname;
        string _lastname;
    }

    function addPerson(string memory _firstname,string memory _lastname) public{
        people.push(Person(_firstname,_lastname));
        peopleCount +=1;
    } 
}
```

And In this program I used mapping and both give me the same result. Can anyone tell me what is the difference.

Comment: Array and mappings - uses, differences, using them together for practical purposes: https://medium.com/robhitchens/solidity-crud-part-1-824ffa69509a

Answer (score 1):

If you need any of the following to run in `O(1)` operations:

- Get an item by unique ID which is **not a sequential number** (e.g., an address)
- Remove an item

Then an array is inappropriate, and you must use a mapping.

Answer (score 0):

From Solidity read the docs:

**Array:**

- Arrays can have a compile-time fixed size, or they can have a dynamic size.
- Indices are zero-based.

Takeaway: Solidity does not support heterogeneous arrays yet, i.e. the indices for arrays are integers and not any other value.

**Mapping:**

- Mapping types use the syntax mapping *(_KeyType => _ValueType)* and variables of mapping type are declared using the syntax *mapping(_KeyType => _ValueType) _VariableName*. The **_KeyType** can be **any built-in value type, bytes, string, or any contract or enum type.**

Takeaway: Scenarios where you need the _keyType to be bytes, string, or even an integer a mapping can be used.

Even though the same work can be done by using an array in struct, places where you need a key other than an integer, where you want to access elements in O(1) time, where you do not want to perform an iteration or loop to find an element etc mapping should be used.

I hope it helps.

**References:**

[Arrays](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.4/types.html#arrays)

[Mapping Types](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.4/types.html#mapping-types)